What is the most optimal choice and best practice when iterating through datasets
So im trying to iterate through some fundus images but my ipynb file keeps crashing. There are only 3662 images, is there a more optimal way of iterating through my entire data? The sole purpose for this is just visualization and exploring the data.Therefore i will use a dataloader once the data is cleaned but for now i'd like to iterate over the entire dataset
#load in the train data - explore and clean
training_images=[]
missing_labels=[]
#count the sample distribution per class 
count={"No DR" :0 , "Mild DR": 0, "Moderate DR": 0, "Severe DR": 0, "Proliferative DR" : 0}



#iterate through the data in subsets, iterating through 200 images at a time
for chunk in np.array_split(df, 1000):
     for idx ,i in tqdm(chunk.iterrows(), total=len(chunk)):
        try:
            img_path = os.path.join(path, f"{i['id_code']}.png")
            img = cv2.imread(img_path, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
            label = i["diagnosis"]
        
            if pd.isna(label):
                #if any image within the csv file does not contain a label, we append the image to the missing_labels, in which we can later filter out
                missing_labels.append(np.array(img))

            #convert each image into a one hot encoding
            #np.eye() allows you define the number of output classes and the [] after it defines which class will be hot
            #np.eye(2)[0] for instance meaning [1,0], we have 2 classes and the 0th index is hot meaning that is our true label
            training_images.append([np.array(img),np.eye(5)[int(i["diagnosis"])]])    

        except Exception as e:
            print(f"There was an error processing  Image : {img_path}")

print(training_images[0][0].shape)
print(training_images[0])        

#as the label and image will be a list of lists, this should return a numpy array and its corresponding one hot encoded
print(f"The number of msising labels found in the dataset are : {len(missing_labels)}")



im not using cv2.imshow() hence i dont think there would be a need to destroy the windows, is this how people typically iterate through their data?

You're putting the image in training images even if it doesn't have a label (and creating an extra copy of it in that case). But you probably shouldn't load all of the images into memory at the same time anyway...

no i was putting the images that dont have a label into missing_labels list.
'' missing_labels.append(np.array(img))''

You're not elseing there, so you're putting them in training_images too.

Something that can significantly affect memory usage is the resolution of the images. If the images are 1024x1024, thats 11 GB of RAM. When the images are loaded into Python, they are decompressed which increases the memory load. This is a small thing but cv.imread() returns a numpy array so you don't need to call np.array() on it.

Resize images to a smaller resolution if needed (maybe 224x224)
Avoid calling np.array() on the image

#load in the train data - explore and clean
training_images=[]
missing_labels=[]
#count the sample distribution per class 
count={"No DR" :0 , "Mild DR": 0, "Moderate DR": 0, "Severe DR": 0, "Proliferative DR" : 0}



#iterate through the data in subsets, iterating through 200 images at a time
for chunk in np.array_split(df, 1000):
     for idx ,i in tqdm(chunk.iterrows(), total=len(chunk)):
        try:
            img_path = os.path.join(path, f"{i['id_code']}.png")
            img = cv2.imread(img_path, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
            img = cv2.resize(img, (224, 224))
            label = i["diagnosis"]
        
            if pd.isna(label):
                #if any image within the csv file does not contain a label, we append the image to the missing_labels, in which we can later filter out
                missing_labels.append(img)

            #convert each image into a one hot encoding
            #np.eye() allows you define the number of output classes and the [] after it defines which class will be hot
            #np.eye(2)[0] for instance meaning [1,0], we have 2 classes and the 0th index is hot meaning that is our true label
            training_images.append([img,np.eye(5)[int(label)]])    

        except Exception as e:
            print(f"There was an error processing  Image : {img_path}")

print(training_images[0][0].shape)
print(training_images[0])        

#as the label and image will be a list of lists, this should return a numpy array and its corresponding one hot encoded
print(f"The number of msising labels found in the dataset are : {len(missing_labels)}")

A last resort is to lazy load the images into PyTorch. You can create a custom dataset with the PyTorch Dataset class and then load the images into memory in __getitem__() instead of all at the beginning, which will make the runtime slower but memory usage will be less.

Thanks a lot, yeah the issue was that the images were of dimensions 2346x3000 which was to large in memory hence the crashing. However would it be possible i use this way of iterating through the dataset as a way of exploring the data and cleaning it up(without augmentation), then passing this saved dataset to the dataloader and using transform there to augment the data
